# Ruby: Open URI. Get file name from the remote url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, open-uri

I have a remote URL, that doesn't have any reference to filename.

https://example.site.com/sadfasfsadfasdfasfdsafas/

But on downloading it gives file as 'Intro.pdf'

I would like to get that filename in my ruby code so that I can use it to create the file or send file in requests. As of now, I am sending the hardcode name as `attachment.pdf`

```
obj = open(url, :ssl_verify_mode => OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE)
data = obj.read
send_data data, :disposition => 'attachment', :filename=>"attachment.pdf"
```

Pls Advice.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check result of `meta` method:

```
p obj.meta
```

probably it have [Content-Disposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields) header. In this case it can have file name as optional parameter.